# delete 's' from all values except that have a digits before 's' in the end of each word

Tags: php

Girl**s** Boy**s** Dog**s** s* 1234567890**s**

my code is look like this

```
<?php
$tags = "john123s ewggw1s friend's piter or girls jumps john's september";
$wordlist = array("or", "and", "where", "a", "the", "for", "is", "out", "!", "?" ,"," ,"." , "' '");

foreach ($wordlist as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';



}
$tags = preg_replace($wordlist, '', $tags);
$words = $tags;
$output = str_replace("'", "", $words);

$output = preg_replace("/s\b/", "", $output);


echo $output;
?>
```

it not ignores john123s and ewggw1s, i tried to write if, but nothing is working...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What script will sort words with and wihout digits, from what to remove s in the end and from what to not.

Comment: The result you are expecting would help out A LOT in this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace("/([^\d])s\b/", "$1", $output);
```

Using the ^ inside brackets means pick anything but NOT this kind of character. Since that means it will also select that letter so we need to grab it in a var using the `( )` and replace that (2 letter) string by the captured letter, so `"$1"` instead of `""`

I suggest you play with it using the functions-online website... I always do that, easy and fast to test code.
http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

This code would remove the `s` that are preceded by a `'` so `Henry's cookies` would become `Henry' cookie` so I suggest you add the ' character in the negation pattern, making it like this:

```
$output = preg_replace("/([^\d'])s\b/", "$1", $output);
```

And you would then remove the line so you keep the ' characters...:

```
$output = str_replace("'", "", $words);
```

Unless you are really expecting something special out of it, there is no reason to butcher english like so... Do not forget that `Dismiss`, and a lot of other words finish in `s` not just 3rd person verbs and plurial nouns...

Comment: But, is there a script to prevent 's' remove if there is two ss at the end?

Comment: Simply use the logic I have pointed out with the exclude part... `[^\d's]` but that will not work for all the words listed here http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/s/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the negative lookbehind `/(?<!x)y/` this means find all "y" not preceded by "x"

```
$output = preg_replace("/(?<![0-9])s\b/",'',$output);
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that... Way better than my futile hack :)